# What are the true signs of haters?

Tags: social-psychology, social-networks, self-control, social-cognition, social

What are the real signs of haters? The reason I asked this question is that I encountered people who treated me badly with criticism now and then. I suspected that they hated me, but I cannot find any valid proof because I don't know what they are thinking.

I tried looking on Google and I found this article:
https://www.elitedaily.com/life/10-signs-youre-a-hater-and-need-to-stop

However, I cannot find more details about the article's author. That website, Elite Daily is not a psychology website or a self-development website.
Therefore, I don't know whether I can trust the article. I tried looking for details on Psychology Today, but I cannot find anything relevant to this question.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. Just a word of advice regarding information seeking, [don't just blindly trust what you are told](https://www.whatstheproblem.co.uk/truth-vs-lies-dont-blindly-trust-what-you-are-told/) **even from those with a PhD or more**. Always check. [Psychology Today is a prime example](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2362/is-psychology-today-a-credible-source). Many authors hide behind their doctorates and are either too lazy to provide citations for their claims or just cannot prove what they say is true. We expect proof in answers for that reason.

Comment: @Chris Rogers. Thanks for the links.